# # sign is missing from dial screen of the emulator

Tags: android

Android: #(hash) sign doesn't show up on dial screen of the emulator or in a real device!

it shows only * and numbers? how I can send it to the dial screen? however i used another action such as (Intent.ACTION_CALL), but same result nothing change!

```
 Inetent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890*#")); 
 startActivity(i);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544579/dial-screen-doesnt-display-hash-sign-either-in-emulator-or-a-real-device

Answer (score 1):

**# symbol** has a [special meaning in URIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String)), so you have to encode it using the `Uri.encode()` method like this:

```
    Inetent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("1234567890*#")));
    startActivity(i);
```

Or You may use special character map to initiate # key as

```
    Inetent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "1234567890*" + "%23")));
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        final String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
         i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890*"+encodedHash)); 
         startActivity(i);
```

'#' is reserved for Uri.. see:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html